# Ubuntu 18.04 won't load on Hyper-V

Tags: 18.04, hyper-v

I'm running a VM of Ubuntu 18.04. I was able to install with no issues. However now when I boot up the VM it will start the boot process and then hang. specifically after a message that reads

```
plymouthd:284 map pfn expected mapping type unchached-minus for [mem xf8800000-xf8bcbfff1] got write-back
```

This will display twice. Then the system will say stopping User Manager for UID 121 then display the message 2-3 more times

I've googled and haven't really been able to find anything and I tried completely reinstalling ubuntu as well as deleting and recreating the VM from scratch. No luck.

Comment: Bump for this, I'm having a very similar problem that's affecting my existing Ubuntu 18.04 VM's on Hyper-V where known good VM's are hanging on a reboot stopping with the "Stopping User Manager for UID 121..." message. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVmy8.png From @Lakewood

Comment: Can you boot without Plymouth? You'll need to get into grub, and update your kernel parameters. Info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Debugging